# How to import only ONE user out of many based on the route params?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, store

my store:

```
store={
  users: [
    {id:1},
    {id:2},
    {id:3}
  ]
}
```

Now, I want to import only one of the users based on the route params eg.

```
id = this.props.match.params.user_id;
```

The question is.. How to establish the id variable above before the mapStateToProps function fetches the data from my store? My mapStateToProps:

```
return {
  singleUser: state.users[id]
};
```

Returns undefined. I tried placing the variable 'id' inside the mapStateToProps but I THINK the params aren't established by the time it starts fetching data.

EDIT: Also, I can't establish the id variable in mapStateToProps because this.props is undefined outside of the component.. how would i go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the array method [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the object with the matching `id`.

```
return {
  singleUser: state.users.find(user => user.id === id)
};
```

Comment: OMG I haven't taught of that :D Thank you!

Comment: Nevermind, I can't establish the id variable in mapStateToProps because this.props is undefined outside of the component.. how would i go about that?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the user object to get the desired user.

`singleUser: state.users.filter(user => {user.id == id})[0];`

`filter` will return an array so you will need `[0]` to get the matched object. In your actual code, you might want to handle edge cases like when the ID doesn't exist.

Also, if you are not targetting internet explorer you can try `find`. It returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function.

```
return {
  singleUser: state.users.find((user) => {user.id === id})
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const id = ownProps.match.params.product_id;
    return {
      user: state.users.find(user => user.id === Number(id))
    };
};
```

The `this.props` of the component can be made available through the second parameter of `mapStateToProps()`. **ownProps** in the example above.